# Angular 2 Router and AuxRoutes

Tags: navigation, typescript, angular, router

Can anybody offer me a bit of advice or even if this is possible with the router in Angular 2.

I have an application with a menu which shows the various components in the router-outlet and these components can have child components which the router all handles.

What I know want to try and now achieve is to add dynamic tab pages to the page and the application as a whole run independently in each tab page (I suppose just like opening a second tab in the browser). A use case would be to have a single menu, but create two tab pages and to be able to route to the customer component on each tab. Each tab would then be able to show two different customer records.

I think AuxRoute will achieve this by naming the router-outlet in each tab.

The problem I see is that I will require RouteConfig for each tab/auxroute I create and as I want the user to create as many tabs as they can (within reason) I will need to dynamically add the routes which I'm guessing would be a big overhead?

IS their a solution to the problem, any advice on how to approach this would be welcomed!

Comment: no i don't think angular2 provide such functionality to create routeConfig dynamically instead you have to prewrite whole routes in your app.